# css/js is not working after add htacess

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

i have `.htaccess` file and this is a script within it:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>


Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^register/$ index.php?c=Page&a=register [L]


</IfModule>
```

in my layout file, i load css and js with absolute path like this:

```
<link href="/public/assets/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/public/assets/bower_components/bootstrap-extension/css/bootstrap-extension.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and i access `localhost/project/register/` but

the css/js file is not loaded bacause of error:

```
GET http://localhost/public/assets/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED
```

why it directly access to `/public` after `localhost`? it should be `localhost/project/public` not `localhost/public`

if i remove first / at css link it access to `localhost/project/register/public`

Comment: because i need every assets folder is based on `/project` folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your css link is not correct. It is starting with `/public` which means Apache will attempt to find it in the `public` folder under site root.

You should update your path to relative one:

```
<link href="public/assets/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="public/assets/bower_components/bootstrap-extension/css/bootstrap-extension.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And then add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML:

```
<base href="/project/" />
```

so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.

Alternative to `<base ../>` tag in HTML, you can use this redirect rule in your .htaccess as very first rule:

```
RewriteRule ^public/.+\.(?:css|js)$ /project%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```

However do note that a redirect rule (even with `R=301`) will still make a new client to send 2 requests to your web server. First with `/public/...` URI and 2nd a `/project/public/...` URI after redirect.

Comment: wow it's working ,you save my time, but is there any solution with htaccess file and without base tag? because i dont want it can be edited on inspect element

Comment: ok I will add a .htaccess solution also but this one is more preferred one.

Comment: and one more, how to define `project/public/`  as pubic folder in htaccess , so i just have to write 'assets/cssfile.css'

Comment: Just change above redirect rule to: `RewriteRule ^assets/.+\.(?:css|js)$ /project/public%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,NE,R=301]`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have two separate questions.

For your question, there is nothing in that .htaccess rule you've shown which would change the way that an existing .css or .js file would be displayed. And so, very likely either your links weren't working before, or you had some other content in the file before to rewrite the URLs differently that you have removed. That file is simply stating that if a URL is given and there is no file or directory which matches it, then rewrite the URL for a certain URL. That does seem to be a mistake, since the URL either exists or does not.

Your second question is about the URLs and why you don't have `/project` in them. I'm not certain why you believe they should have `/project` in them, but I'm assuming that you had assumed that because your original HTML is in that directory. You are starting your link with a `/`, as in `/public/assets/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"`. That `/` means that the path is absolute, rather than relative, meaning that the path is started directly after the hostname. If you remove the initial `/`, then the path would be relative to the URL that it is called from.

Comment: yes, there is nothing rule to change the existing .css file, because i don't know it and i'am new in htaccess, and what am i asking for is what is rule that can solve it, i mean what is rule that declare  `project` is base url. so i don't have to use `project/public` to access .css file

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load these files relative to the domain root and the `public` directory is not in the domain root, you'll need to provide the ***full*** domain relative path:

```
<link href="/project/public/assets/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/project/public/assets/bower_components/bootstrap-extension/css/bootstrap-extension.css" rel="stylesheet">
```